# Linux file privileges

Tags: linux

How can I check and set who can view or open a given folder or file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check:

```
ls -l /path/to/folder/or/file
```

or for more verbose output:

```
stat /path/to/folder/or/file
```

To change owner:

```
chown someuser:somegroup /path/to/folder/or/file
```

To change permissions:

```
chmod 755 /path/to/folder/or/file
```

**man chown** and **man chmod** will give you explanation about the various options.

Or, if you are using some graphical environment, such as Gnome, you can just right-click the files/folders and set the permissions there.

**EDIT**: Changed file -> stat. Thanks for correction!

Comment: This suffices 99% of the time.  The other 1% of the time (when access control lists are in use) you need `getfacl filename`.

Comment: Marius: And for the 0.01% of the time (when SELinux security contexts are in use) you need to use -Z flag for various commands, such as ls, to see the SELinux flags.

Comment: `file` doesn't show anything about permissions. Perhaps you meant `stat`. Also, some people find symbolic permissions to be more intuitive: `chmod u+x,g=rx,o-w abc` or `chmod ugo=r abc`